# How to add watermark while record video using ffmpeg

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I am recording square video using following ffmpeg library. Square Video recorded successfully with audio but now i want to add watermark on video but my application crashed and getting error. Please help me how can i add watermark while record video.

Gradle dependency

```
compile(group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'javacv-platform', version: '1.3') {
    exclude group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets'
}
compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'ffmpeg', version: '3.2.1-1.3'
compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'ffmpeg', version: '3.2.1-1.3', classifier: 'android-arm'
```

I am using following code for add watermark while record video

```
     // add water mark
            String imgPath = audioPath + "jodelicon.png";
            String watermark = "movie=" + imgPath + " [logo];[in][logo]overlay=0:0:1:format=rgb [out]";
            filters.add(watermark);
```

Complete Code

```
 class VideoRecordThread extends Thread {

        private boolean isRunning;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            List<String> filters = new ArrayList<>();
            // Transpose
            String transpose = null;
            android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info =
                    new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
            android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(mCameraId, info);
            if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
                switch (info.orientation) {
                    case 270:
//                        transpose = "transpose=clock_flip"; // Same as preview display
                        transpose = "transpose=cclock"; // Mirrored horizontally as preview display
                        break;
                    case 90:
//                        transpose = "transpose=cclock_flip"; // Same as preview display
                        transpose = "transpose=clock"; // Mirrored horizontally as preview display
                        break;
                }
            } else {
                switch (info.orientation) {
                    case 270:
                        transpose = "transpose=cclock";
                        break;
                    case 90:
                        transpose = "transpose=clock";
                        break;
                }
            }
            if (transpose != null) {
                filters.add(transpose);
            }
            // Crop (only vertically)
            int width = previewHeight;
            int height = width * videoHeight / videoWidth;
            String crop = String.format("crop=%d:%d:%d:%d",
                    width, height,
                    (previewHeight - width) / 2, (previewWidth - height) / 2);

            filters.add(crop);
            // Scale (to designated size)

            String scale = String.format("scale=%d:%d", videoHeight, videoWidth);
            filters.add(scale);

            // add water mark
            String imgPath = audioPath + "jodelicon.png";
            String watermark = "movie=" + imgPath + " [logo];[in][logo]overlay=0:0:1:format=rgb [out]";
            filters.add(watermark);

            FFmpegFrameFilter frameFilter = new FFmpegFrameFilter(TextUtils.join(",", filters),
                    previewWidth, previewHeight);
            frameFilter.setPixelFormat(avutil.AV_PIX_FMT_NV21);
            frameFilter.setFrameRate(frameRate);
            try {
                frameFilter.start();
            } catch (FrameFilter.Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            isRunning = true;
            FrameToRecord recordedFrame;

            while (isRunning || !mFrameToRecordQueue.isEmpty()) {
                try {
                    recordedFrame = mFrameToRecordQueue.take();
                } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                    ie.printStackTrace();
                    try {
                        frameFilter.stop();
                    } catch (FrameFilter.Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    break;
                }

                if (mFrameRecorder != null) {
                    long timestamp = recordedFrame.getTimestamp();
                    if (timestamp > mFrameRecorder.getTimestamp()) {
                        mFrameRecorder.setTimestamp(timestamp);
                    }
                    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
//                    Frame filteredFrame = recordedFrame.getFrame();
                    Frame filteredFrame = null;
                    try {
                        frameFilter.push(recordedFrame.getFrame());
                        filteredFrame = frameFilter.pull();
                    } catch (FrameFilter.Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        mFrameRecorder.record(filteredFrame);
                    } catch (FFmpegFrameRecorder.Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    long processTime = endTime - startTime;
                    mTotalProcessFrameTime += processTime;
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "This frame process time: " + processTime + "ms");
                    long totalAvg = mTotalProcessFrameTime / ++mFrameRecordedCount;
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Avg frame process time: " + totalAvg + "ms");
                }
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, mFrameRecordedCount + " / " + mFrameToRecordCount);
                mRecycledFrameQueue.offer(recordedFrame);
            }
        }

        public void stopRunning() {
            this.isRunning = false;
            if (getState() == WAITING) {
                interrupt();
            }
        }

        public boolean isRunning() {
            return isRunning;
        }
    }
```

Error in logcat

```
android A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x18 in tid 320 (Thread-24542)
```

Comment: Hi @hitesh, Have you found any solution?